# Value change sub - select next selected cell

Tags: vba, excel

I have a private sub (triggered by value change). When the sub has finished, the target cell is automatically selected. How do I change this so that the next cell that would have been selected (ie in absence of the sub) is selected? Eg if the user hit “enter” the cell below the target cell is selected, if they hit ”Tab”, the cell to the right,or on mouse click, the cell selected in that case?
TIA

Comment: Welcome! You're going to need to [edit] your question to clarify what you have, if you need some help with something.  Include the code you have so far, sample data if applicable, and a little background information.   Check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!)  See "[ask]" as well as [mcve], and see the [help/on-topic] for more information about what's on-topic on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save current location to a variable and then re select it with range and the variable

```
Dim currentCell as String
currentCell = ActiveCell.Address
‘All your other code
Range(currentCell).Activate
```

Comment: Thanks - the first line proiduces an run-time error: Object variable or With block variable not set. NB I'm pretty new to VBA :)

Comment: Okay seemed to fix by Dim currentCell as string - thanks so much!!